# How to save a Spark LogisticRegressionModel model?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using MLlib 1.1.0 and struggling to find a way to save my model. [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel) do not seem to support such as feature in this version. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is save model option like:

```
// Save and load model
model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
val sameModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
```

But I see it starting from v1.3. I m not sure if it will be still valid for 1.1 
You can try this and upgrade if it does not work??

Comment: That's right. It starts from 1.3.0 but I cannot update unfortunately. I ended up with this `sc.parallelize(List(model)).saveAsObjectFile("model.mdl")` for now - although I had to increase akka frame size to 32 MB. Any alternative?

Comment: Umm, you want to save it for later use in another spark app?

Comment: yes exactly. what is the minimum effort / code required to implement `model.save()` myself? thanks!

Comment: I am not so sure how hard it could be. You can have a look at the code in github and try.  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/MatrixFactorizationModel.scala